# After updating my nvidia drivers via the .run, my system no longer boots

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia-geforce, additional-drivers

I updated my nvidia drivers and I can boot to the decryption screen, but I can't figure out how to access the grub menu or find a way out of this. Pressing ctrl+alt+f2 (after decryption) shows a terminal, but it's unusable and just shows the blinking cursor.

Comment: Try another virtual term like crtl+alt+f3 or f4.  login and purge all nvidia packages, then ubuntu-drivers list  then pick the latest driver for your hardware (which you didn't specify), and ubuntu-drivers install <pkg>. reboot.Some random nvidia driver from the ...run script will cause problems, if not immediately, upon kernel upgrade.